# Factory Girl - Manipulate Transient Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a use case where I would like to manipulate a transient attribute in a factory based on the traits that are included. Is there a way to do this, or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Let's say I'm building a `House` object. The `house` can have many `windows`. I want to create some sub-factories that will automatically create some windows, but I want to be able to *add a trait for a specific type of window*. The `window_types` transient attribute is actually a list of traits for the `window` factories.

```
factory :house do
  floors 3
  exterior 'Brick'

  transient do
    window_types { [:bay, :double_hung] }
  end

  trait :with_picture_window do
    window_types.push(:picture)
  end

  factory :ranch_house do
    floors 1

    after(:create) do |house, evaluator|
      evaluator.window_types.each do |window_type|
        FactoryGirl.create :window, window_type
      end
    end
  end

  factory :mountain_house do
    floors 2
    exterior 'Log'

    after(:create) do |house, evaluator|
      evaluator.window_types.each do |window_type|
        FactoryGirl.create :window, window_type
      end
    end
  end
end

factory :window do
  material 'Glass'

  trait :bay do
    # bay window attributes
  end

  trait :double_hung do
    # double hung window attributes
  end

  trait :picture do
    # picture window attributes
  end
end
```

This throws a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'push' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit>` error from within the `:with_picture_window` trait.

For the sake of argument, assume that I *do* need different factories for these houses. Is there a way that I can modify the **window_types** transient attribute from within a trait, and then have that transient attribute be reflected in my sub-factories?

I would like to be able to do:

```
FactoryGirl.create :ranch_house
# creates a ranch house with only bay and double_hung windows

FactoryGirl.create :ranch_house, :with_picture_window
# creates a ranch house with bay, double_hung, AND picture windows
```

If not, is there a better way that I can accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a suitable solution based on the idea presented by Ben. I used a local array variable to store the types of windows that needed to be created. The traits for each window add a type of window to the array in the `after(:build)` block. Then, in an `after(:create)` block I actually create the window records.

The very first `after(:build)` block (the one not in a `trait`) is important because that resets the `window_types` array between object creation.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  window_types = []

  factory :house do
    floors 3
    exterior 'Brick'

    after(:build) do
      window_types = []
    end

    after(:create) do |house|
      window_types.each do |window_type|
        FactoryGirl.create(:window, window_type, house: house)
      end
    end

    trait :with_picture_window do
      after(:build) do
        window_types << :picture
      end
    end

    trait :with_double_hung_window do
      after(:build) do
        window_types << :double_hung
      end
    end

    trait :with_bay_window do
      after(:build) do
        window_types << :bay
      end
    end

    factory :house_with_bay_and_picture_window, traits: [:bay, :picture]
  end
end
```

I'm very curious to hear any thoughts on this approach. For now, this suits my needs and is very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will answer your question but commenting would be useless with the formatting limitations. Perhaps the followign pattern could be useful in solving this?

```
trait :with_window do
  after(:build) do |house|
    # Create a house window
    house.windows << FactoryGirl.build(:window) #Presume you could also pass a window trait here.
  end
  after(:create) do |room|
    # Clear the windows attached in after(:build) and create one without saving the house again
    house.windows.each do |window|
      window.house_id = house.id
      window.save
    end
    house.reload
  end
end
```

Hope this provides help in some way!

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and I was optimistic about this approach, but unfortunately this results in a `stack level too deep` error. I believe the problem is in the `after(:build)` with `house.windows << FactoryGirl.build(:window)`. The only way that `house.windows` can keep track of that new `window` is through the foreign key that doesn't yet exist since the `house` has not been saved. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a `stack level too deep` error, that was something else. In reality, the `window` record was failing validation during the `house.windows << FactoryGirl.build(:window)` step, because the `house` didn't yet have an ID to associate with the window. However, I think I can use local variables for this... I'll post another answer.